# How to disable encryption on local xmpp network

Tags: encryption, xmpp, ejabberd

I want to see plain xml text of xmpp messages content for developing , debugging ,etc
so I've installed 'ejabberd' as xmpp server and 'empathy' as xmpp client.(i track packets with wireshark)
i think it should be done by changing configuration in xmpp server , but i don't know how ?!
I would like someone to guide me through disabling encryption and see xmpp request in plain text form in wireshark.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ejabberd.cfg,  in the listen section, look for configurations for ejabberd_c2s.
Comment out the lines specifying the the certificate and starttls support.
Without starttls, no encryption will be offered (you might need to confirm on your client that you *want* to connect without encryption as some clients prevents that by default).